# Solve $x^2-4x+3 = 0$ for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As part of another problem, I have to solve  $x^2-4x+3 = 0$  for x. However, I am not sure how to handle $x^2$.

$$x^2-4x+3 = 0$$

$$x(x-4)+3 = 0$$

$$x(x-4) = -3$$

Comment: See [the quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation),  Or, more simply, try to factor the quadratic.

Comment: Hint: Find two numbers that multiply to $3$ and add to $-4.$

Comment: @lulu Could you please tell me how I can use the quadratic equation to find x here?

Comment: It's an entirely standard application of the formula. Though, as I say, this particular problem is easy to solve by simple factoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $x^2-4x+3 = (x-1) (x-3).$

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like
\begin{align}
x^2-4x+3=&0
\\
x^2-4x+4-1=&0
\\
x^2-4x+4=&0+1
\\
x^2-2\cdot 2\cdot x+2^2=&1
\\
(x-2)^2=&1
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are solved in many ways. For example,

$$ x_{1,2} = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} }{2a} $$

For instance, in your problem, we have $a=1, b= -4$ and $c=3$. Can you find $x_{1,2}$?

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-4x+3 = x^2-3x-x+3 = \dots$

Can you take it from here?